# Increment counter upon field input with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, counter, increment

I want to create a contact form field (not visible for users) whose linked button-less counter increments by 1, as soon it is filled in the source code (for this reason I chose the input function, irrespective of the number of chars entered). With an input value != 0, the form submission will be prevented afterwards. If I test it (in “visible” mode over my IDE preview website) and input something, the counter works and shows “1”.

[image: see here]

If I delete my input, click into it and input something again, it doesn’t increment further and still shows “1”. This all is without refreshing my page, storing the counter value in local.storage keeps displaying the “1” on my page.

```js
$("#mail_conf").on("input", function(){
  $("#counter").html(function(val){
    return val+1;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="email" id="mail_conf" name="user_email_conf" placeholder="E-mail conf.*">
<div id="counter">0</div>
```

Comment: May I ask what the purpose of this counter is? It seems like you’re trying to assess whether the `<input>` has, or has had, an entry? But then you’re preventing form-submission if data has been entered?

Comment: If you're using a `<form>` and `<input type="email />` your form shouldn't be submitted until the input is validated by the browser.

Comment: Please check my answer and mark if it resolves your issue, please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark below the score.

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica - Exactly, it serves as a kind of statistics for how many, let's say, unwelcome visitors stranded there without having to collect their IPs in a database etc.

Comment: @Andy yes, I also implemented a submit function = false if length>0

Answer (score -1):

```js
$("#mail_conf").on("input", function () {
  // first arg is index, 2nd is oldhtml. `+val` converts the string to an int
  $("#counter").html("1")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="mail_conf">
<p id="counter">0<p>
```

Does this solve your issue?

The problem that I notice is that you are trying to use `.html()` with a  function, which as per the documentation returns as first argument `index` and `oldhtml` as 2nd argument. https://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is not exactly what I am looking for, as this acts like a kind of change function (counting every character), it should return e. g. "1", if 1 or even 500 characters are entered

Comment: @Ann-Diana your initial question and ID names are misleading. Based on your initial inquiry, I understood that you needed a counter (esp judging by the element ID name). If you want to display `1` every time the value is changed, just use this: `$("#counter").html("1");`

Comment: many thanks for getting back, it shall display 1 for the first visitor inputting something, 2 for the next one and so on... sorry if this was misleading, this input field is intended to trap bots

Comment: @Ann-Diana you can't do that with JavaScript alone. There is no way for JS to remember visitors since it runs locally on the visitor's computer. For this, you would need a server-side counter and you'd use JavaScript Fetch API or XHR to trigger it. Using localStorage you can count how many times the same user has visited the page.

Comment: Although this is not optimal news for me (I was hoping much less would be involved and obviously need to become familiar with the server side now, lol), I am very thankful for your valuable information